# Any pytorch tools to monitor neural network's training?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch

Are there any tools to monitor network's training in PyTorch?

I am looking for an equivalent to tensorboard in tensorflow.

Answer (score 4):

I am using [tensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX). It supports most of the features of TensorBoard. I am using the Scalar, Images, Distributions, Histograms and Text. Haven't tried the rest like audio and graph. But the repo also contains examples for those usecases. Installation can be done easily with pip. It's all explained in the readme.

There are also other software which implement a wrapper for PyTorch (and other languages/frameworks) of TensorBoard. As far as I know, they support fewer functionalities. But have a look at [Crayon](https://github.com/torrvision/crayon) and [Tensorboard-Logger](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/tensorboard_logger).

Answer (score 2):

I am also using [Tensorboard-PyTorch](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch) (TensorboardX). Over all I am quite happy with it.

But don't try to visualize graphs. At least none with a bit of complexity (e.g. a resnet50 won't work). There are some issues about it on [their github page](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch/issues/7).

But better check out the Pytorch forum frequently. Pytorch seems to move quite fast. And a direct tensorboard implementation [is planned](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/print-autograd-graph/692/2?u=xwgeng), as well.